# Do strings need to be escaped inside parametrized queries?

Tags: sql, node.js, express, pg, prepared-statement

I'm discovering Express by creating a simple CRUD without ORM.

Issue is, I'm not able to find any record through the `Model.findBy()` function

```js
model User {
  static async findBy(payload) {
    try {
      let attr  = Object.keys(payload)[0]
      let value = Object.values(payload)[0]

      let user = await pool.query(
        `SELECT * from users WHERE $1::text = $2::text LIMIT 1;`,
        [attr, value]
      );

      return user.rows; // empty :-(
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }
}

User.findBy({ email: 'foo@bar.baz' }).then(console.log);
User.findBy({ name: 'Foo' }).then(console.log);
```

I've no issue using `psql` if I surround `$2::text` by single quote `'` like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'foo@bar.baz' LIMIT 1;
```

Though that's not possible inside parametrized queries. I've tried stuff like `'($2::text)'` (and escaped variations), but that looks far from what the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) recommends.

I must be missing something. Is the emptiness of `user.rows` related to the way I fetch `attr` & `value` ? Or maybe, is some kind of escape required when passing string parameters ?

---

***"Answer":***

As stated in the comment section, issue isn't related to string escape, but to dynamic column names.

Column names are not identifiers, and therefore cannot be dynamically set using a query parameter.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50813577/11509906

Comment: I don't know your environment, but I would think that `where $1::text =` will be replaced with `where 'email' =` - and thereby no match possible. Usually you can't change table or column names with parameters.

Comment: That SQL statement appears incorrect, what is your expectation? You don't need to escape strings using parameterised queries but your where-criteria is just comparing two strings, are you intending for the *column* to be dynamic? If so you cannot do that.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. My goal is to find a user based on the object's key passed in parameter (`email`, `name`) and use the object's value (`foo@bar.baz`, `Foo`) as value. If I cannot dynamically set the column's name in the `WHERE` statement, I'll go for another approach

Comment: is `$1` supposed to be a column name? Does your database library allow identifiers (column/table/database name etc) to be parameterized? If `value` is of type JavaScript string, do you still need to cast it using `::text` or does the database library do it for yu?

Comment: Indeed, column names are NOT identifiers. Not tested yet, but this looks good to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50813577/11509906